# Download select files from NOAA in R

Tags: r, csv, noaa

I have a list of files I found on the NOAA website with this URL:

https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/gsoy/access/

I would like to know how I can load only specific files into R from here.

Comment: Yes. Are are not forced to load all the files. I'm not exactly sure what your real question is though. Do you have a list of the files that you want to load? Do you want to load them all into different data.frames?

Comment: See my response to Anonymous coward below. It is fine if they are in different data frames.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a case where you'll treat it like an `FTP`.

```
library(RCurl)
url = "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/gsoy/access/"
filenames = getURL(url, dirlistonly = TRUE)
filenames <- strsplit(filenames, "\r\n")
filenames <- unlist(filenames)

download_filenames <- c("ZI000067781.csv", "ZI000067755.csv") #specify what files you want, do this in whatever way you desire, with a regex, list, etc.


sapply(download_filenames, function(x) {
  download.file(paste(url, filename, sep = ""), paste(getwd(), "/", filename,
                                                                                        sep = ""))
}) #apply a download to your file names
```

You could also successively read the `csv` you wanted into a dataframe. Like MrFlick said, not sure what exactly you want.

Comment: I don't have the names in front of me, but say I want to download the files ACW00011647, AGM00060403, and ARM00087016. It is fine if they are in different data frames. I simply need to load the files into R.

Comment: Also, the sapply function does not seem to work for me when I replace "filename" with the actual names? I do not see the dataframes show up in my global environment after running the code.

Comment: If you replace "filename" within the `sapply` function it will not work. You'd have to just run the `download.file` part on its own with one file name. The `sapply` loops over the `download_filenames`. If you wanted to download those three, place them in the `download_filenames` part, i.e. `download_filenames <- c("ACW00011647.csv", "AGM0006043", "ARM00087016")`.